# holdoff after failed Kafka messages

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a sping boot Kafka consumer annotated with @Listener. This works great. I want to handle failed messages by sending them to another topic (DQL). Still quite easy to do with an ErrorHandler.

There are two types of fault situations:

- deserialize problem and so the consumer is not called
- exception in the consumer

The first situation can be nicely handled by pausing the container. The container instance is passed with the call used when a deserialize error occurs.
But... If the poll went fine and all 500 messages are received I can't stop them from being sent to the consumer. So if there is something wrong during the processing of the messages it will always fail the complete 500 messages. I can't figure out how to stop the batch in a nice way.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

I also tried to lower the maxPollRecords after a fault but that heavily relies on reflection and is far from a nice way to stop flooding the system with faults.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage DLQs in either of these ways as per your implementation requirement.

1. If you are using Kafka Connect, I would request you to refer [confluent blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/)
2. If you are using Kafka Streams, then refer to this  [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#default-deserialization-exception-handler).
3. If you have your own producer and consumers, Then in your try-block, add kafka consumer logic & if any exception occurs send the message to “Dead Letter Queues (DLQs)” topic. If there is no error send the message to “target-topic” after transformation.

Comment: I'm using option 3: But the issue remains that the poll in Spring-Boot received a whole bunch of messages and those will be delivered to the listener. I would like to not keep delivering faults to the DLQ but slow delivering down until the problem is fixed.

Comment: Well in that case you might want to have a look into : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek-to-current. It says - 'If an ErrorHandler implements RemainingRecordsErrorHandler, the error handler is provided with the failed record and any unprocessed records retrieved by the previous poll(). Those records are not passed to the listener after the handler exits.'

This should help I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds promising. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

> **This is not a solution to your problem but to point out a subsequent problem if you find a clean solution to pause the consumer**

**1. Lets say you can hold off after first failed Kafka message**

i.e a solution exists to pause the consumer (like the code below) as soon as the first error occurs.

**2. Subsequent problem**

- **But** once the consumer is paused, your next poll will not happen for a while and when it is beyond `max.poll.interval.ms`, Kafka will consider your consumer dead and revoke the partition.
- **How will you restart the consumer once the problem is fixed?**

**3. Pseudocode for your first issue**

```
boolean failed = false;

@KafkaListener(id = "baz", topics = "myTopic",
          containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {

   
    if(failed)
        Thread.sleep(500000);
    try {

        //YOUR MESSAGE PROCESSING

        ack.acknowledge();

    } catch(Exception e){
        failed = true;
        ack.acknowledge(); //acknowledge it as it goes to DLQ via error handler
        throw e; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this could work and could be that Ill use something like this. But for now I would like to keep error handling separate from the consumer code.

Comment: But my point is once you find a solution(whatever it is), you have a problem restarting the consumer because kafka would have revoked the partition. So whatever clean solution you find to pause the consumer, you also need to find a way to restart a consumer